# How to search through a man page?

Tags: command-line, grep, manpage, pipe

I often want to search through a `man` page, however I am forced to either do:

```
man <package> | grep <search>
```

Or:

```
man <package> > file.txt
```

But there must be an easier way than this to do this, so how can I search through a `man` page while in it instead of having to send its contents to a file, or use `grep` to print the necessary matching contents to standard output?

Comment: `grep` should work perfectly like `man something | grep what_to_search`  if you want to save it as a file `man something | grep what_to_search >file.txt`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can pipe `man`'s output just fine, know that you can search within `man` as well. `man` uses `less` as the pager by default, and within `less`, you can:

- press `/` and enter the text you wanted to search for
- press `n` to go the next search result and `N` to go the previous search result
- press `g` to go to the top (since the search doesn't wrap around by default)

Also see:

- [Tricks and tips for finding information in man pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/tricks-and-tips-for-finding-information-in-man-pages)

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you specify which man page you want.  For example, if you want to look up any information to do with "version" on the `ls` command, you could type:

```
man ls | grep version
```

which will return the matches of "version" from the ls man pages.

Comment: To improve the output, you could use `grep -C 2` or `grep -B 2 -A 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can read `man` pages in `emacs`, with <kbd>ESCx</kbd><kbd>m a n</kbd>, and leave the opened `man` page in an invisible, "buried" buffer for later re-use.

Comment: Interesting idea