# How can I search the APT man page for options to install

Tags: command-line, apt, manpage

I read the answer [wireless - How can I check the information of currently installed WiFi drivers? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333424/how-can-i-check-the-information-of-currently-installed-wifi-drivers) and learn a command

```
sudo apt-get install -y hardinfo
```

then I tried to find the option `-y` in the `man` page

```
me@alpha:~$ man apt-get | grep '-y'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
me@alpha:~$ man apt | grep '-y'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
me@alpha:~$ man install | grep '-y'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
me@alpha:~$ man 'apt install'
No manual entry for apt install
```

How could I get a manual about options to `apt install`?

Comment: The errors here are because `grep` is interpreting `-y` as a command line option - you can prevent that by marking the end of options using `--` e.g. `man apt-get | grep -- '-y'` but TBH it's probably more helpful to search interactively *within* the man page by as described here [How to search through a man page?](https://askubuntu.com/a/665407/178692) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is actually `apt`, not `install`.  The man pages can be viewed by

`man apt`

and

`man apt-get`

In this specific case, `sudo apt install <program-name>` asks you if you really want to install before it proceeds.  The `-y` option prevents apt from asking if you want to install - it assumes "yes"